# is there a way to run the same job multiple times without scheduling it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent, jobs, process

I have to run a process, and it says:

```
    --first see what is the situation with the job
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name=N'Create new gift vouchers'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Create new gift vouchers' ; 
-- RUN THIS JOB FOR AS MANY TIMES AS THERE ARE INSERTS ABOVE --> 2 IN THIS CASE
    GO
```

this time I need to run the same job (that executes a SSIS package and takes about 8 min on average to run) for 15 times!!!

is there a way to put a script together that will run this job 15 times?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the process to see if there is a way to batch that job.  Maybe record the record(s) that require the job to be run and then run it once for all of them, periodically thoughout the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the following stored procedure (I can't even remember where I got the code from) for a long time.  It allows you to start a job and waits for the job to complete before returning control to the user.  You could stack 15 occurrences of this call in a tsql script

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[StartAgentJobAndWait](@job nvarchar(128), @maxwaitmins int = 5) --, @result int output)
as begin

set NOCOUNT ON;
set XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

    declare @running as int
    declare @seccount as int
    declare @maxseccount as int
    declare @start_job as bigint
    declare @run_status as int

    set @start_job = cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) as bigint) * 1000000 + datepart(hour, getdate()) * 10000 + datepart(minute, getdate()) * 100 + datepart(second, getdate())

    set @maxseccount = 60*@maxwaitmins
    set @seccount = 0
    set @running = 0

    declare @job_owner sysname
    declare @job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    set @job_owner = SUSER_SNAME()

    -- get job id
    select @job_id=job_id
    from msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
    where sj.name=@job

    -- invalid job name then exit with an error
    if @job_id is null
        RAISERROR (N'Unknown job: %s.', 16, 1, @job)

    -- output from stored procedure xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs is captured in the following table
    declare @xp_results TABLE ( job_id                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
                                last_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
                                last_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
                                next_run_date         INT              NOT NULL,
                                next_run_time         INT              NOT NULL,
                                next_run_schedule_id  INT              NOT NULL,
                                requested_to_run      INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL
                                request_source        INT              NOT NULL,
                                request_source_id     sysname          COLLATE database_default NULL,
                                running               INT              NOT NULL, -- BOOL
                                current_step          INT              NOT NULL,
                                current_retry_attempt INT              NOT NULL,
                                job_state             INT              NOT NULL)

    -- start the job
    declare @r as int
    exec @r = msdb..sp_start_job @job

    -- quit if unable to start
    if @r<>0
        RAISERROR (N'Could not start job: %s.', 16, 2, @job)

    -- start with an initial delay to allow the job to appear in the job list (maybe I am missing something ?)
    WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:01';
    set @seccount = 1

    -- check job run state
    insert into @xp_results
    execute master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

    set @running= (SELECT top 1 running from @xp_results)

    while @running<>0 and @seccount < @maxseccount
    begin
        WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:01';
        set @seccount = @seccount + 1

        delete from @xp_results

        insert into @xp_results
        execute master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, @job_owner, @job_id

        set @running= (SELECT top 1 running from @xp_results)
    end

    -- result: not ok (=1) if still running

    if @running <> 0 begin
        -- still running
        return 0
    end
    else begin

        -- did it finish ok ?
        set @run_status = 0

        select @run_status=run_status
        from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
        where job_id=@job_id
          and cast(run_date as bigint) * 1000000 + run_time >= @start_job

        if @run_status=1
            return 1  --finished ok
        else  --error
            RAISERROR (N'job %s did not finish successfully.', 16, 2, @job)

    end

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE
        @ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(4000),
        @ErrorNumber     INT,
        @ErrorSeverity   INT,
        @ErrorState      INT,
        @ErrorLine       INT,
        @ErrorProcedure  NVARCHAR(200);

    SELECT
        @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

    SELECT @ErrorMessage =
        N'Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d, ' +
            'Message: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();

    RAISERROR
        (
        @ErrorMessage,
        @ErrorSeverity,
        1,
        @ErrorNumber,    -- original error number.
        @ErrorSeverity,  -- original error severity.
        @ErrorState,     -- original error state.
        @ErrorProcedure, -- original error procedure name.
        @ErrorLine       -- original error line number.
        );

    END CATCH

end


GO
```